# jQuery : load a plugin using on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I'm using jQuery and Tooltipster (showing tooltips when going hover user names), which are working great **except for one situation** : when I first go hover a user name, it does not show up.

```
<div class="user">Firstname Lastname</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseover', '.user', function() {

    // Tooltip for EC user
    $('.evac_user').tooltipster({
        animation : 'fade',
        delay : 0,
        content : 'Loading...',
        functionBefore : function(origin, continueTooltip) {
            continueTooltip();

            // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
            if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : "/myfunction",
                    success : function(data) {
                        // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                        origin.tooltipster('update', data).data('ajax', 'cached');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Explain whats going wrong and provide a fiddle svp

Comment: I already explained what was wrong in my question and I can't provide a fiddle because it's using ajax + an external jQuery plugin...

Comment: No you haven't you said: `which are working great except for one situation : when I first go hover a user name.` what is going wrong when you hover over a user name

Comment: Also its not too hard to mimic the ajax in fiddle - just update the content in a `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question, I hope it's clear like that. I have no idea how to make the fiddle though.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.user').on('mouseover', function(){
```